# Binding file in singularity

Tags: image, mount, singularity-container

I created an singularity image with my script. I need to run my app using a local file with parameters for the script. for this I want o use --bind parameter. It works perfectly fine if I try to do:

```
singularity run --bind /my/source/file:/destination/file my_app_image.img <input.txt >output.txt
```

But I would like to run it directly like this:

```
./my_app_image.img --bind /my/source/file:/destination/file <input.txt >output.txt
```

but this does not work - file is not mounted in the destination. How can I mount a file during runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Although I worked for some time with singularity containers, I don't know if this is possible.

If you have to call an executable in your use case, you could write a short wrapper script that calls `singularity run ...` and binds the file into the container.

You can also ask your question on the [Singularity user list](https://groups.google.com/a/lbl.gov/forum/#!forum/singularity).

P.S. I wanted to comment, but do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

you  can export your bind directory/file before a call the container like an executable.

```
 export SINGULARITY_BINDPATH="/my/source/file:/destination/file"
 ./my_app_image.img <input.txt >output.txt
```